# Updating mysql database table with variable from php calculation

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am making an addition using php and I want to update the output to a column from my database.

This is what I have:

```
$api = "https://blockchain.info/ticker";

$json = file_get_contents($api);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$rate = $data["USD"]["sell"];
$symbol = $data["USD"]["symbol"];
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bit_buysell WHERE status='1' ORDER BY id");
if($query->num_rows>0) {
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo ''.$row[name].' '.$row[currency].''.$row[price].'';
    }
}

echo "<br><center> <b>1 BTC = " . $rate . $symbol . "</b></center></div>";
?></li>

<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bit_buysell WHERE id='1' ORDER BY id");
if($query->num_rows>0) {
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo ''.$row[prce].'';

        $first_number = $rate ;
        $second_number = $row[price];
        $sum_totalbuy = $first_number * $second_number;

        print ($sum_totalbuy);
    }
}
```

I have been able to successfully add the the bitcoin price ticker and my custom value which returns the result I want in the `print ($sum_totalbuy);`

I want to therefore update my database by changing a table which automatically reference the `$sum_totalbuy`

Here is what i have done -

```
mysql_query("UPDATE bit_rates SET id='38' WHERE rate_from='$sum_totalsell'");
```

it didn't work and I have this too which I don't know how to go about it

Here is the code that manually update it via my dashboard, because I have to enter rate from and rate to:

```
<div class="card-body">
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>List with exchange rates</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="rid">
            <?php
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bit_rates ORDER BY id");
            if($query->num_rows>0) {
                while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.gatewayinfo($row[gateway_from],"name").' '.gatewayinfo($row[gateway_from],"currency").' ('.$row[rate_from].' '.gatewayinfo($row[gateway_from],"currency").') = '.gatewayinfo($row[gateway_to],"name").' '.gatewayinfo($row[gateway_to],"currency").' ('.$row[rate_to].' '.gatewayinfo($row[gateway_to],"currency").')</option>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<option>No gateways</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>New exchange rate</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Rate from</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rate_from" placeholder="1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">=&nbsp;&nbsp; Rate to</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rate_to" placeholder="0.95" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_update_rate"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Update</button>
</form>
```

Please help me fix it.`$sum_totalbuy`

I need to store the `print ($sum_totalbuy);` to be updated in `rate_from` I will handle `rate_to $sum_totalbuy`

Comment: Your code does not use the mysql api, so mysql_query() could not possibly work...

Comment: you need to use `$db->query()`, not `mysql_query()`.

Comment: ...well, definitely not mysql_query

Comment: Pls can you teach me how to do it?

I've multiplied the 2 most important things which gives me 'print ($sum_totalbuy); I just now actually want to update a table in my database to always change to whatever comes out of 'print ($sum_totalbuy);' because it always changes with Bitcoin price as it fluctuates.

Comment: @Shadow pls show me how

Comment: @Barmar I've tried something similar. Can't get anything to update that value in the affected database table. Pls teach me

Answer (score 0):

i have finally gotten it to work and this is what i did.
I had to do a total reconnect to my database then did the query update.

```
 <?php
$server = "host"; 
$user = "user"; 
$pass = "pass"; 
$db = "db";
// Create connection  
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);    
// Check connection    
if (!$conn) { 
    die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "UPDATE bit_rates SET rate_from='$sum_totalsell' WHERE id=38";  
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Sell Rate Update successful.";
} 
$sql = "UPDATE bit_rates SET rate_to='$sum_totalbuy' WHERE id=37";  
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Buy Rate Update successful.";
} 
else {
    echo "Could not update: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);  
?>
```

That directly updates the table in my sql

Thanks everyone for the time

i found the help here https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/mysql-update-syntax/

Comment: The question doesn't show the original, incorrect code. How can we see what you changed?

Comment: Is this the same script or a different script from the one you showed in the question? Of course you need to reconnect if it's new script.

Comment: What I was initially trying to do was that I wanted to do a multiplication of Bitcoin live rate with my own number say ex. 6000(btc/1) x 400

So that brought me to sum_totalbuy which is the result of both.

Why 8 came to stack is because I needed to now update my database with that result so it becomes automatically updated always as I've always updated it manually.

I then had to reconnect my database inside of the page where it is useful so that it can always store the sum_totalbuy and sum_totalsell in there respective tables